# AngularJS [Ionic] - Google apis XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: angularjs, json, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

I would like get the json data from Google Api but with get method and jsonp method this is not work.

Her is my code :

```
        $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=46.2030350,6.1522080&radius=500&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY&callback=?'
    }).then(function successCallback(response,data) {
        console.log(data)
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('nope')
    });
```

I'have `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly like you are trying to run the `file` without a `server` directly via browser. You would need either xampp or other webserver.

OR just install `python 2.7` and use the following command from where your project files are location `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and then navigate to `localhost:8000`

Comment: Hum, i'm on angular with Ionic Framework, it's for an app Android- iOS